# In Ruby, foo.inspect can print out all instance variables -- can we print out an individual one if there is no accessor?

Tags: ruby

Often, we can use `p foo` or `foo.inspect` to see the instance variables, but is it only the default behavior and the object can choose to show something else (or hide all instance variables) (probably by re-defining the `inspect` method).

The main question is, if I can see for `foo.inspect` that there is `@bar` being an object, having instance variable `@wah`, that has a value of `"hello"`, can I print out `@wah` directly, if there is no accessor (reader) available for `@bar` and `@wah`?   Usually, it should not be readable if there is no accessor, but what if for debugging purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ruby, all access protection can be circumvented using reflection:

```
@bar.instance_variable_get(:@wah)
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to print a variable defined by attr_writer from outside the class will throw an error (`undefined method 'wah' for #<Bar:0x0000...>`)  - but for debugging purposes you can use [instance_variable_get](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001028) as such:

```
b = Bar.new(:wah => "Hello")
b.wah # undefined method

b.instance_variable_get("@wah") # => "Hello"
```

Comment: This is because attr_* generates methods, not variables.